# Overriding System.Exception serialization

Tags: .net, exception, serialization

I would like to skip serialization of some of the properties of `Exception` class like `StackTrace` and `RemoteStackTrace` (need this for custom error processing in context of WCF). How can i do that? I would be happy to set their values to `null` in `GetObjectData()` but i can't because underlaying fields are private (why the heck do they always make them private instead of protected?)

Comment: You can't.  I can't offer an alternative either because you made no effort describing why you'd contemplate breaking the Exception class this badly.  These fields are private for a good reason.

Comment: Why is this breaking? Neither StackTrace nor RemoteStackTrace are vital for Exception to serialize. I just don't want to serialize sensitive data (security issues).

Comment: Have you tried using faults instead?

Comment: Marc, i do use typed faults but they have some limitations, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucky me, `Message` property is virtual and other ones i need have public setters so i can just disable inherited (de)serialization code:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class MyErrorBase : Exception
{
    protected string reason;

    public string TrackingID { get; set; }

    public override string Message
    {
        get { return reason; }
    }

    public MyErrorBase() : this(null) { }

    public MyErrorBase(string reason) : base(reason)
    {
        this.reason = reason;
        // other init logic
    }

    protected MyErrorBase(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        HelpLink = info.GetString("HelpLink");
        Source = info.GetString("Source");
        TrackingID = info.GetString("TrackingID");
        reason = info.GetString("Reason");
    }

    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Reason", reason);
        info.AddValue("TrackingID", TrackingID);
        info.AddValue("Source", Source);
        info.AddValue("HelpLink", HelpLink);
    }


}
```

Suprisingly, disabling the inherited logic looks absolutely fine for CLR when re-throwing deserialized instances.

For those interested why i need this. My custom WCF error handling is inspired by this awesome [article](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/simplifying-wcf-using-exceptions-as-faults/). So instead of trivial plain fault classes my faults are derived from `MyErrorBase` and my operation contracts look like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(InvalidState))]   
void Action();
```

Where `InvalidState` is inherited from `MyErrorBase`. This works fine because `Exception` is marked with `[Serializable]` - that's enough for `DataContractSerializer`. But you don't want any details like stack trace to be exposed as a result of your service call, do you?

The resulting envelop (now) looks like the following:

```
  <s:Fault>
     <faultcode>s:InvalidState</faultcode>
     <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Cannot be processed in its current state.</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <InvalidState xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNS" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
           <Reason i:type="x:string" xmlns="">Cannot be processed in its current state.</Reason>
           <TrackingID i:type="x:string" xmlns="">50547779-06d4-470d-ae75-a9feb3e08a99</TrackingID>
           <Source i:type="x:string" xmlns="app1"/>
           <HelpLink i:type="x:string" xmlns="">blabla</HelpLink>
           <State i:type="x:int" xmlns="">2</State>
        </InvalidState>
     </detail>
  </s:Fault>
```

The most benefit is that non .NET consumers are still fine (full SOAP compatibility and we don't expose sensitive data) but .NET consumers of the service now can extract the fault as .NET exception and re-throw it on the client (or handle faults usual way). This is much better than handling `FaultException<T>` because you can organize your faults as a hierarchy and enjoy inheritance in catch-blocks. `FaultException<T>` fails here because of type (in)variance.